# android - recyclerview cannot click and get position

Tags: android

I have tried some code to can click recyclerview item and get position, but I can't click the recyclerview item.. the data I get from url. So I wan't switch activity with get the item user click..

how I can fix that?

this code for adapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private static final String TAG = RecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;

    ImageLoader imageLoader1;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context) {

        super();
        this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

        GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 = getDataAdapter.get(position);

        imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                )
        );

        Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);

        Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return getDataAdapter.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
        public NetworkImageView networkImageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item);

            networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1);
        }
    }
}
```

and this code for mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;

    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://androidblog.esy.es/ImageJsonData.php";
    String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME = "image_title";
    String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "image_url";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;

    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);


                JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();


    }

    public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleNamee(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

getdataadapter

```
public class GetDataAdapter {

    public String ImageServerUrl;
    public String ImageTitleName;

    public String getImageServerUrl() {
        return ImageServerUrl;
    }

    public void setImageServerUrl(String imageServerUrl) {
        this.ImageServerUrl = imageServerUrl;
    }

    public String getImageTitleName() {
        return ImageTitleName;
    }

    public void setImageTitleNamee(String Imagetitlename) {
        this.ImageTitleName = Imagetitlename;
    }


}
```

Comment: You  need to set `onClickListener` to your item view! Get a item view by calling `holder.itemView` in your adapter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a listener on your recycler item view and then in onclick, start intent to open new activity. Pass the data object you want to pass with the intent.

//make sure your model class GetDataAdapter implements Parcelable

```
holder.itemView.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityToOpen.class);
            intent.putExtra("key",Your Object to pass);// getDataAdapter1 in your case
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

then in your Startted activity receive your object like this

```
 YourObject obj = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key");
 //Your case
GetDataAdapter obj = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key");
```

Comment: you want to open activity on item click and pass clicked object to that activity right?

Comment: then in your onBindViewHolder simply put the listener like this

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `onClickListener` to your item view. You can do by following below steps:

Set `onCLickListener` to root view of your list item.

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);
```

Add below code in `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        // Add your logic here
            }
        });
```

You can add listener while `onBindViewHolder`:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        // Add your logic here
            }
        });
```

Thanks.